# IIS7 Multiple Sites with redirection on domains for SEO purposes

Tags: iis-7, seo, domains, bindings, redirect

For SEO purposes with IIS6, I had always set up two sites, one bound to www.domain.com and another site to domain.com that redirects to www.domain.com where the actual site lived.

I really hate the clutter and duplicates in IIS (call it being anal detective, I don't know!?) but is there a better or more elegant solution to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, URL Rewrite is the tool of choice for this situation.  Awesome solution for not just this, but most everything else you could want regarding SEO friendly URLs.

Links:

- [IIS.Net Resource](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/).
- Here are some [blogs and videos](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/tags/URL+Rewrite/default.aspx) I've put together for URL Rewrite.  One of them talks specifically about adding the www.

Comment: Excellent! I use URL Rewrite all over the place. Not sure why I didn't think to use it for 301 Redirect to "www." Thanks Scott.